# Snowflake Date range query for historical data and add a delta

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake SQL and writing a requirement to get historical dashboard.

Requirement is to get the data 5 years from current data + want to include the whole of the first month of the past 5th year. For example if today is 26-05-2021, we would need to get the data from
01-05-2016 to 25-05-2021.

Using my present Snowflake SQL query, I get the data of last 5 years, is it possible in Snowflake inbuilt to get the delta of remaining days.

```
select * from table where portion_start >= trunc(add_months(sysdate(),-12*5),'YEAR')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
select * 
from table 
where portion_start >= dateadd(year,-5,date_trunc(month,current_date()))
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!